# Can't get Microsoft.ProjectOxford.Vision or REST method working in PCL

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, computer-vision, azure-cognitive-services

This should be pretty straightforward, but I can't get it to work. I'm using [these](https://blog.xamarin.com/performing-ocr-for-ios-android-and-windows-with-microsoft-cognitive-services/) instructions. I've tried using the Nuget package in my PCL targeting 259 as as well as in another PCL targeting 7. Both PCLs never return after these lines. I've tried both.

```
//text = await client.RecognizeTextAsync(imageURL);
text = await client.RecognizeTextAsync(imageURL, languageCode: "en", detectOrientation: true);
```

Here is the REST code I've also tried. This works with my HTTP Helper.

```
public static async Task<OcrResults> PostReceiptAsync(string imageURL)
{
    try
    {
        var apiKey = "KEY 1";
        var content = await HttpHelper.Request(null, String.Format("https://eastus2.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/vision/v1.0?language=en&detectOrientation=true&subscription-key={0}&url={1}", apiKey, imageURL), null, HttpRequestType.POST);
        return Mapper<OcrResults>.MapFromJson(await content.ReadAsStringAsync());
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

In both methods, I'm trying to use a Blob image URL. Here is my calling method.

```
takePhoto.Clicked += async (sender, args) =>
{
}
```

It's almost seems like a deadlock issue.

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

UPDATE: I finally got the REST method to work with Android and UWP using this bit of code, but it fails in my iOS app. The main problem I had is that the URL that you copy out of Azure does not include the ocr? parameter. The Json Mapper is something that my SDK uses. OcrResults comes from the Project Oxford Nuget package.

```
public static async Task<OcrResults> ProcessReceiptAsync(string imageUrl)
{
    // Instantiate a HTTP Client
    var client = new HttpClient();
    var apiKey = "KEY 1";
    // Request parameters and URI
    string requestParameters = "language=en&detectOrientation =true";
    string uri = "https://eastus2.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/vision/v1.0/ocr?" + requestParameters;
    // Pass subscription key thru the HTTP Request Header
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", apiKey);
    // Format Request body
    byte[] byteData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes($"{{\"url\": \"{imageUrl}\"}}");
    using (var content = new ByteArrayContent(byteData))
    {
        // Specify Request body Content-Type
        content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
        // Send Post Request
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(uri, content);
        // Read Response body into the model
        //return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync(OcrResults);
        var result = Mapper<OcrResults>.MapFromJson(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
        return result;
    }
}
```

UPDATE 2: This method also works on Android and UWP, but fails with a BadRequest in my iOS app. I wanted to change up how the image URL gets encoded.

```
public static async Task<OcrResults> ProcessReceiptAsync2(string imageUrl)
        {
            // Instantiate a HTTP Client
            var client = new HttpClient();
            var apiKey = "KEY 1";

            // Request parameters and URI
            string requestParameters = "language=en&detectOrientation =true";
            string uri = "https://eastus2.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/vision/v1.0/ocr?" + requestParameters;

            // Pass subscription key thru the HTTP Request Header
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", apiKey);

            // Format Request body
            var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            dict.Add("url", imageUrl);

            //var param = JsonConvert.SerializeObject($"{{\"url\": \"{imageUrl}\"}}");
            var param = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dict);
            HttpContent contentPost = new StringContent(param, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

            // Specify Request body Content-Type
            //contentPost.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            // Send Post Request
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(uri, contentPost);

            // Read Response body into the model
            //return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync(OcrResults);
            var result = Mapper<OcrResults>.MapFromJson(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
            return result;

        }
```

UPDATE 3: I tried this code, but it failed with a Bad Request on iOS. I'm using the ExtractTextFromImageUrlAsync. I did get a "file too large" error using the ExtractTextFromImageStreamAsync, so that method appears to have worked.

https://github.com/HoussemDellai/Microsoft-Cognitive-Services-API/blob/master/ComputerVisionApplication/ComputerVisionApplication/Services/ComputerVisionService.cs

UPDATE 4: I removed Microsoft.Net.Http 2.9 from all the Projects and commented out System.Net.Http from all the app.config files. Both methods now work in the Android and UWP app. I still can't get the iOS app to work. The Project Oxford Nuget fails at this line requestObject.url = imageUrl; (see GitHub). The Rest method fails with a Bad Request, but I managed to catch a "InvalidImageUrl" message, so something is happening when the imageUrl is encoded. At this stage, I believe this is a Xamarin issue that's specific to iOS 10.4.0.

Comment: Not sure if you still have an issue or not

Comment: It works in my Android Project, but in my iOS Project, I get this error.  {StatusCode: 400, ReasonPhrase: 'Bad Request', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
{
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
apim-request-id: 6c786d34-8335-48e7-acf1-3c2267eaf8e2
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload
x-content-type-options: nosniff
Date: Tue, 23 May 2017 02:52:18 GMT
Content-Length: 118
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Expires: -1
}}

Comment: When you are using the ProjectOxford.Vision NuGet, are you making sure to update your Endpoint when initializing? I wonder if the reason it is not returning is because you are going to the wrong endpoint. I noticed, in your case, your endpoint is in eastus, whereas looking at the SDK code the default API root is westus.

So for you it would be:
`var client = new VisionServiceClient("Your_API_Key", eastus2.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/vision/v1.0/)` 

I would confirm this and then test your actual call to `RecognizeTextAsync()`